# Ruby on rails using post method to redirect to another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-post

as one of you said in my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365768/ruby-on-rails-password-is-visible-in-url-as-parameter) question, i attempted to make a post request.

Here is my login view

```
<%= form_for :check_validity, :method => "post", :url => {:action => "check_validity"} do |f| %>            
              <%= f.label :username %>
                  <%= f.text_field :username %><br />
                  <%= f.label :password %>
                  <%= f.password_field (:password)%><br />
                  <%= f.submit "Submit"%>
                <% end%>
```

Since the `check_validity` is a `post` method, i wrote the below code in my post method

```
def check_validity
     @USER = params[:display_command_list][:username]
     @PASS = params[:display_command_list][:password]      
     @HOST = 'hostname'
     Net::SSH.start( @HOST, @USER, :password => @PASS ) do|ssh|
     @result = ssh.exec!("command")
     end
         if(@result =~ /somestring/)
          redirect_to display_command_list_path({:username => @USER, :password => @PASS})
         else
          redirect_to denied_access_path
         end
  end
```

But when i enter username and password in login page and click on submit button, it goes to this post method and gives me `"Missing template authorization/check_validity"` error. I included `post "authorization/check_validity"` in my `routes.rb`. It seems that i'm missing something very basic here :(. Please let me know why is it not able to redirect to the paths i mentioned instead of looking for `check_validity.html.erb`

I remember when we scaffold, and click on new post and submit it, it redirects to create method which is a post request and then automatically redirects to show method which is `'get'.` How is it able to understand that it should go to 'show' after create? I tried to replicate that here but failed. Please help.

Update: I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985596/redirect-to-using-post-in-rails) and understood that we should not use redirect in a POST method. But how would i use this information and go to `denied_acess_path` or `display_command_list_path` from this `check_validity` method

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right controller action?

Comment: @nicholaides i found that i should not be using redirect, the controller has 'check_validity' action with method 'post' and added the route post "controller/check_validity' in my routes.

Answer (score 0):

i think i solved the problem.

In the login method i used the following code

```
  def login

  respond_to  do |format|   
  format.html
  end

  end
```

When i removed the respond_to block, i was able to execute the code. But i still do not know why this is happening. Is the respond to tag looking for check_validity.html.erb instead of login.html.erb?

Comment: That `respond_to` block is incorrect. You are missing the `do`. Or is that a typo?